# magento newsletter keeps returning an error even after email is saved

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, newsletter

There was a problem with the subscription.
this is the message I get after I enter an email. When I go to the admin panel the email is added. 
I would like it NOT to display this message. any suggestions please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only place in Magento that error string occurs is in the following try/catch block

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/controllers/SubscriberController.php
try {
    //...snip!...
}
catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
    $session->addException($e, $this->__('There was a problem with the subscription: %s', $e->getMessage()));
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    $session->addException($e, $this->__('There was a problem with the subscription.'));
}
```

Since you reported the error message as "There was a problem with the subscription.", that means the newsletter subscription code is throwing some sore of PHP exception, caught by the `catch (Exception $e) {` block.  Magento does not output the messages from PHP exceptions.  If I was in your position I'd temporarily change the exception handling code to include the error message

```
    $session->addException($e, $this->__('There was a problem with the subscription. ' . $e->getMessage()));
```

This will let you track down the PHP error that's triggering your error message.

Per the comment below, the only place the "Cannot set standard header from `addHeader()`" exception error exists is

```
#File: lib/Zend/Mail.php
    $prohibit = array('to', 'cc', 'bcc', 'from', 'subject',
                      'reply-to', 'return-path',
                      'date', 'message-id',
                     );
    if (in_array(strtolower($name), $prohibit)) {
        /**
         * @see Zend_Mail_Exception
         */
        #require_once 'Zend/Mail/Exception.php';
        throw new Zend_Mail_Exception('Cannot set standard header from addHeader()');
    }

    $value = $this->_filterOther($value);
    $value = $this->_encodeHeader($value);
    $this->_storeHeader($name, $value, $append);

    return $this;
```

My guess is somewhere in your system someone's added some custom code that tries to set one of the standard email headers via the `addHeader` method.

Comment: thanks Alan. it returned ...There was a problem with the subscription. Cannot set standard header from addHeader()